# wine as root? how to solve

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

I learning Electron. Ubuntu 16. I just made my first electron app and try to compile it for windows. I use [this guide](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/). But, when I try to make

```
sudo electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="shoppingcard"
```

i get an error

```
rcedit.exe failed with exit code 1. wine: /home/uses/.wine is not owned by you
```

I even didnt use wine and install it only to compile my program. And all manuals says dont run wine as root. I dont know how to fix this.

upd.

```
uses@pinkya-spot:~$ id
uid=1000(uses) gid=1000(uses) группы=1000(uses),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare)
uses@pinkya-spot:~$ ls -la /home/uses
итого 220
drwxr-xr-x   30 uses uses  4096 Врс 25 02:05 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  root   4096 Врс 20 00:39 ..
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:54 .adobe
drwxrwxr-x    9 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 03:31 .atom
-rw-------    1 uses uses  3886 Врс 25 01:43 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 uses uses   220 Врс 20 00:39 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--    1 uses uses  3771 Врс 20 00:39 .bashrc
drwx------   18 uses uses  4096 Врс 24 02:10 .cache
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 01:17 .compiz
drwx------   24 uses uses  4096 Врс 23 03:09 .config
drwx------    3 root  root   4096 Врс 20 03:31 .dbus
-rw-r--r--    1 uses uses    25 Врс 20 00:50 .dmrc
drwxr-xr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 23 02:11 .electron
-rw-r--r--    1 uses uses  8980 Врс 20 00:39 examples.desktop
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 24 22:31 .gconf
-rw-rw-r--    1 uses uses    95 Врс 20 03:04 .gitconfig
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 24 22:30 .gnupg
-rw-------    1 uses uses  6760 Врс 24 22:30 .ICEauthority
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:50 .local
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:54 .macromedia
drwx------    4 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:53 .mozilla
-rw-------    1 uses uses     3 Врс 20 01:36 .node_repl_history
drwxrwxr-x 1031 uses uses 36864 Врс 24 02:00 .npm
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 01:23 .nv
drwx------    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 01:27 .pki
-rw-r--r--    1 uses uses   655 Врс 20 00:39 .profile
-rw-------    1 uses uses   256 Врс 20 21:53 .pulse-cookie
drwx------    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 16:01 .putty
drwxrwxr-x   20 uses uses  4096 Врс 24 00:01 .steam
drwxrwxr-x    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 21:53 Steam
lrwxrwxrwx    1 uses uses    30 Врс 24 00:00 .steampath -> /home/uses/.steam/bin32/steam
lrwxrwxrwx    1 uses uses    28 Врс 24 00:00 .steampid -> /home/uses/.steam/steam.pid
-rw-r--r--    1 uses uses     0 Врс 20 01:25 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwx------    4 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 01:55 .thunderbird
drwxrwxr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 25 02:05 .wine
-rw-------    1 uses uses    56 Врс 24 22:30 .Xauthority
-rw-------    1 uses uses   200 Врс 25 01:37 .xsession-errors
-rw-------    1 uses uses  2293 Врс 24 12:25 .xsession-errors.old
drwxr-xr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:50 Видео
drwxr-xr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:50 Документы
drwxr-xr-x    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 24 22:45 Загрузки
drwxr-xr-x    3 uses uses  4096 Врс 24 02:09 Изображения
drwxr-xr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:50 Музыка
drwxr-xr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:50 Общедоступные
drwxr-xr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 21 04:44 Рабочий стол
drwxr-xr-x    2 uses uses  4096 Врс 20 00:50 Шаблоны
```

upd.

```
uses@pinkya-spot:~$ ls -al ~ | grep wine
drwxrwxr-x    4 uses uses  4096 Врс 25 16:24 .wine
```

Comment: Well? Do you own `/home/uses/.wine`? Run the commands `id` and ``ls -la /home/uses`` and [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: **Scott**, done

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. OK, it sure looks like you own `/home/uses/.wine`. I’m afraid I don’t have a clue what the problem is; maybe this detailed information will help somebody else to figure it out.

Comment: **Scott**, i think the problem is that i use electron compile command with `sudo`. But i dont know how to pass this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I joined Slack channel and asked this question. Electron Packager maintainer **malept** (Mark Lee) helps me to solve this problem. There was no reason to start Electron Packager as root. I just needed to create output (`--out=...`) folder with permission to write.